# Shell Read string from one file and replace in other file

Tags: shell, awk

My requirement is to read the string from input file and replace all its occurrences with replaced string into output file. 
Example:

```
$ cat input
BOB_XYZ  "JOB.ABC"
ROB_LOLA  "TOT.XYZ"
$ cat output
{
BOB_XYZ is a BOB_XYZ
I am BOB_XYZ
}
```

Here, I need to replace "BOB_XYZ" with "JOB.ABC" from output file. I mean expected output as

```
$ cat output
{
"JOB.ABC" is a "JOB.ABC"
I am "JOB.ABC"
}
```

Please let me know, how we do this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
cat $1 | while read ORIGINAL REPLACEMENT; do
  sed -ie "s/$ORIGINAL/$REPLACEMENT/g" $2
done
```

Note that this makes a lot of assumptions about the input and output files; e.g. that you have IFS set appropriately, you're not using '/' or certain other characters in ORIGINAL or REPLACEMENT, etc.

Comment: Note that you'd call this as e.g. "replacements.sh input output", and it would overwrite output in place.

Comment: Instead of executing `sed` at every iteration you could build up the entire line and pass it to `ed`, or use a process substitution. `sed -f <(while read o r; do printf 's/%s/%s/g\n' "$o" "$r"; done < input) output` or `while read o r; do printf '1,$s/%s/%s/g\nw\n' "$o" "$r"; done < input | ed output`. For that matter, if there are exactly two arguments on each line: `printf ',s/%s/%s/g\nw\n' $(<input) | ed output`

Comment: @kojiro, Thanks for the solution, I liked this simple way

Answer (score 1):

Using awk, here is one way to do it. Loop through `input` and `output` files, collecting the "variables" from `input` into an array `a` and applying field-by-field replacements on `output`

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1]=$2; next};
    {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i in a) $i=a[$i]; print}' input output
```

Comment: Above awk solution works , but I wanted replaced strings  into the same "output" file and not on console

Comment: @user2803710 then redirect the output to a file.

Comment: Redirecting to the same file will either fail (if you have <code>set noclobber</code> in your shell), or will overwrite the file when the command starts, truncating output to length 0.